# Two uwsgi django websites on same domain using nginx

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a django website `site1` running  on a linux machine.

It has the following config:

`site1_nginx.conf`

```
upstream django {
 server unix:///var/www/site1/site1.sock;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name    site.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;  
    location /media  {
         alias /var/www/site1/media;
    }
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/site1/static; 
    }
     location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/site1/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

`site1_uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /var/www/site1
module          = site1.wsgi
home            = /var/www/virtualenv/site1
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /var/www/site1/site1.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

It has a domain `site.com`.

I have another django website `site2` at hand. It's different, has a different virtualenv. I can't add it to the existing website as an app or via django routing. I want the sites to not be related, so that they track sessions separately.

I want the other website `site2` available by address `www.site.com/site2` or as a subdomain `site2.site.com`.

Is it possible? What's the best way to do it? 
I checked uwsgi emperor mode, but it seems I need different domains for that.

EDIT:
I tried to add the second site as a subdomain.
I created the following configs:

```
#site2_nginx.conf

upstream django_site2 {
 server unix:///var/www/site2/site2.sock;
}
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name    site2.site.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;  
    location /static {
        alias /var/www/site2/site2/static; 
    }
     location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django_site2;
        include     /var/www/site2/uwsgi_params;
    }
}


#site2_uwsgi.ini


[uwsgi]
chdir           = /var/www/site2/site2
module          = site2.wsgi
home            = /var/virtualenv/site2
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /var/www/site2/site2.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
```

I added a symlink to the nginx config to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

`site.com` works, but `site2.site.com` says that the page could not be retrieved, so 404.

Comment: Why not using subdomain? like site2.domain.com

Comment: It does not provide any product `core management`, your level is high but want low level managment. `CGI` can do this, how you can create independent for each subdirectory index ? You want use sub directory as sub-domain but cost (resource, security?

Comment: @Beomi actually its acceptable too. I will edit in the answer that it would work too. How can I do that though?

Comment: @Euphe It's called "Server Blocks". like this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-server-blocks-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/
What you hav eto do is let your webserver(nginx) to point your django project by domain name :)